# Laravel database notifications how to display only those notification which created in the current month (displaying current month notifications)

Tags: laravel

laravel database notifications works properly but the problem in here how to display the notification which created in the current year and also month of the system

```
<?php
$user = App\User::first();
foreach($user->unreadNotifications as $notification):?>
<h4>
    {{$notification->data['name']}}
    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o">
        </i>{{$notification->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</small>
</h4>
</a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: as the last point we would like to express that the notifications works properly but i want to display only those notifications that created in the current month not the last months

Answer (score 0):

Take the current year-month and compare it with notification created date(year-month only). Here is the code

```
<?php
$user = App\User::first();
$currentMonth = date('Y-m');
foreach($user->unreadNotifications as $notification):
if(date('Y-m',strtotime($notification->created_at)) == $currentMonth);?>
<h4>
    {{$notification->data['name']}}
    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o">
        </i>{{$notification->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</small>
</h4>
</a>
<?php endif;
endforeach;?>
```

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question?https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers